# How to cause Windbg to download the compressed versions of MS public symbols

Tags: debugging, windbg, debug-symbols

Microsoft state [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/microsoft-public-symbols):

> The Microsoft Symbol Server provides compressed versions of the symbol
>   files. The files have an underscore at the end of the filename’s
>   extension to indicate that they are compressed. For example, the PDB
>   for ntdll.dll is available as ntdll.pd_.

I have 2 questions here:

1. **The more general question:** How can I cause Windbg to prefer the compressed version of the symbols? This would result in massive bandwidth savings. (Compressing c:\Symbols on my computer resulted in a 68% reduction in size).
   Sniffing the traffic reveals that the uncompressed version is tried first and then the compressed version (underscore at end of name).
2. **and specific to MS Public Symbols:** Are the compressed versions currently available at all? Trying to manually download a compressed versions of ntdll.pdb returns a 404 error.

   ```
   >$ wget https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/ntdll.pdb/38A5841BD353770D9C800BF1AF6B17EB1/ntdll.pdb
   ... 
   ntdll.pdb                                 100%[=====================================================================================>]   1.46M   406KB/s    in 4.4s
   2018-11-11 01:16:56 (341 KB/s) - ‘ntdll.pdb’ saved [1534976/1534976]

   >$ wget https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/ntdll.pdb/38A5841BD353770D9C800BF1AF6B17EB1/ntdll.pd_
   ....
   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
   2018-11-11 01:17:01 ERROR 404: Not Found.
   ```

**Update:**

I have now discovered that DbgHelp [supports an option called SYMOPT_FAVOR_COMPRESSED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-symsetoptions#SYMOPT_FAVOR_COMPRESSED) which is explained as follows:

> If there is both an uncompressed and a compressed file available, favor the compressed file. This option is good for slow connections.

The question now is how to enable this option in Windbg?

This option isn't documented in [the officical Windbg documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/symbol-options) and setting it manually seems to only affect the UI level.

```
0:003> .symopt+ 0x800000
Symbol options are 0x830337:
  0x00000001 - SYMOPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE
  0x00000002 - SYMOPT_UNDNAME
  0x00000004 - SYMOPT_DEFERRED_LOADS
  0x00000010 - SYMOPT_LOAD_LINES
  0x00000020 - SYMOPT_OMAP_FIND_NEAREST
  0x00000100 - SYMOPT_NO_UNQUALIFIED_LOADS
  0x00000200 - SYMOPT_FAIL_CRITICAL_ERRORS
  0x00010000 - SYMOPT_AUTO_PUBLICS
  0x00020000 - SYMOPT_NO_IMAGE_SEARCH
  0x00800000 - SYMOPT_FAVOR_COMPRESSED
```

**However inspecting the traffic using fiddler shows that the uncompressed version is still requested first.**

Comment: windbg downloads the compressed version only and it is expanded locally in your machine  there is no bandwudth savings possible here  use procmon or netmon to confirm  the pdb directory is not browsable  you need a curl .wget like app with proper useragent age and guid to retrieve them standalone

Comment: Did you look at the wget session I posted? It shows that the decompressed version (no underscore - I actually opened the file to confirm that it is **not** compressed) is available with plain wget (no user-agent games needed) and the compressed version is unavailable.

Comment: Which version of WinDbg and which version of [dbghelp.dll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/dbghelp-versions) and symsrv.dll do you use?

Comment: FYI: compressing c:\symbols with NTFS compression will save you ~68% disk space.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I am using the latest version of Windbg from the Microsoft Store and it seems to be using DbgHelp version 10.0.18239.1000

Comment: @ThomasWeller my question was about saving bandwidth not disk space.

Comment: @yossizahn: I know, that's why I put it as "FYI"

Comment: SYMOPT_FAVOR_COMPRESSED works for me in 10.0.10586.567. I inspected the traffic with Wireshark

Comment: Probably it won't make much of a difference. The PBDs are requested with `Accept-Encoding:gzip`, so even when downloaded as PDB file instead of PD_, it will be compressed on the fly.

Comment: @ThomasWeller the PDB's are returned without any content/transfer-encoding.

Comment: @ThomasWeller when you say "SYMOPT_FAVOR_COMPRESSED works for me in 10.0.10586.567", is that in windbg or some other program using dbghelp.dll? Also, did it actually dowload compressed symbols, or were they unavailable (404)?

Comment: That was the WinDbg version number. It tries `.PD_` first, which results in HTTP 404, then it tries `.PDB` which works for Microsoft DLLs. It will not download directly bur use a HTTP 302 redirect to some HTTPS blob download site.